# Unknown provider: $ionicAppProvider

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I get this error when I try to set GCM push's api key in app.js

Here is the code I use:

```
.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
    // Identify app
    $ionicAppProvider.identify({
        // The App ID for the server
        app_id: 'MY_APP_ID',
        // The API key all services will use for this app
        api_key: 'MY_API_KEY',
        //The GCM project number
        gcm_id: 'MY_GCM_PROJECT_NUMBER'
    });
  }])
```

Comment: **NB** Ionic Beta Migration (from Alpha..) `ionic-service-core` is replaced with `ionic-platform-web-client` - http://docs.ionic.io/docs/migration-guide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed the ionic-service-core module and setup your app with it. You'll need to do the following:

1) Install Ionic Service Core.
Run `ionic add ionic-service-core` on the command line for your project

2) Add this script tag to index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
```

3) Add the `ionic.service.core` module to your app.js like so:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic',
  'ionic.service.core',
  'starter.controllers'])
```

Comment: I have all of this set, but the error is still there.

Comment: @FernandoFabreti And you are certain that the lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js file exists at the correct path?

Comment: Thanks @jcaruso , but now that I've installed the service and configured the $ionicAppProvider, I not receiving any notification

Comment: @matdev I haven't used push notifications myself, but you may need to include a bunch of other ionic services (similar to ionic.service.core above) in order for that to work. But I'm glad I was able to help you fix the $ionicAppProvider error. There must be some documentation, sample app or a tutorial that you can follow from the ionic website.

Comment: @FernandoFabreti Use grunt instead of adding the script manually into index.html: add ionic-core.js path to your Gruntfile.js and relaunch grunt watch

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've implemented this as mentioned above and I'm still getting the error originally mentioned. I'm thinking that this has been deprecated as the same information lives in .io-config.json.

Comment: You can run `ionic config info` to see the configuration info.

Comment: **NB** Ionic Beta Migration (from Alpha..) `ionic-service-core` is replaced with `ionic-platform-web-client` http://docs.ionic.io/docs/migration-guide

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have injected the ionic core service before your module. Try this:

```
angular.module('starter', [
  'ionic',
  'ionic.service.core',
  'your.module'
]);
```