# Unknown provider: $ionicAppProvider when it exists and defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Similar issue to [Unknown provider: $ionicAppProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211313/unknown-provider-ionicappprovider)

However I have all the elements and everything loaded fine

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'ionic.service.core',
    'ionic.service.deploy',
    'ionic.service.push'
     ...
    ])


.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
     $ionicAppProvider.identify({
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="lib/ionic/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-deploy/ionic-deploy.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-analytics/ionic-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do all those scripts load correctly? No 404's in your *Network* console?

Comment: Also, you seem to be missing the closing `])` for the module dependency array

Comment: @Phil  `]) was left out, its much longer and everything loaded fine

Comment: I don't think you're meant to have both `ionic-service-core` and `ionic-platform-web-client` as the former is deprecated in preference of the latter.

Comment: @Phil commented it out of both, still same issue

Comment: is the required js included in your index.html?